# Good architecture MVC, API-calls

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, architecture

Me and some friends are currently doing a project where we are designing a webpage, where we do a number of api-calls using ajax.

We are using the Angular-framework, and we are wondering what is the correct architecture on where to put the API-calls. Right now we have them in our controllers, and saving the results as $scope-objects.

We are however wondering if it would actually be better praxis to have the API-calls in the model. We have been googling a lot, and can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulating API calls in services is a good idea, but don't try to hide the fact that you are making web requests in your code.  Have the services/model return descriptive promises and have your controller use the promises and handle errors gracefully. If using REST, you might want to use Angular's built in $resource factory. If the code is easy to unit test, it will be a sign that you're doing a good job. Being able to easily mock the services will make your controllers a lot easier to test.

Comment: we have just said the same, I will remove my answer, this website has some good examples https://scotch.io/tutorials/node-and-angular-to-do-app-controllers-and-services